# Properties of Expectation Conditioned on a Function of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I've come across the two following claims regarding the properties of conditional expectation:

$$
\mathsf{E} \Big\{ \mathsf{E}\big[Y\, \big|\, F(X) \big]\; \Big|\; X \Big\} = \mathsf{E}\big[Y\, \big|\, F(X) \big] \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
\mathsf{E} \Big\{ \mathsf{E}\big[Y\, \big|\, X \big]\; \Big|\; F(X) \Big\} = \mathsf{E}\big[Y\, \big|\, F(X) \big]\,, \tag{2}
$$

where $F(\cdot)$ is a given function on the range of $X.$

How does one show this?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$
\sigma \big(F(X)\big) \subseteq \sigma(X)\,.
$$

Therefore, (1) and (2), written above, follow immediately from the tower property.